# Currying in Lisp: difference between (list 1 2 3) and (1 2 3)?

Tags: list, lisp, currying

Is there any difference between `(list f 1 2)` and `(f 1 2)`?

If yes, then is `(f 1 2)` equivalent to `((f 1) 2)` (currying)?

If yes, then is `(a b)` mean "add `b` to the end of list `a`"?

If yes, then what `append` function is for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any difference between (list f 1 2) and (f 1 2)?

Yes: `(list f 1 2)` calls the function `list` with the arguments `f`, `1` and `2`, which creates a list containing those elements. `(f 1 2)` calls the function `f` with the arguments `1` and `2`, which does whatever `f` was defined to do.

> is (f 1 2) equivalent to ((f 1) 2) (currying)?

No. Functions in Lisp aren't curried automatically. If you call a function as `(f 1 2)` it must be a real binary function, not a curried function.

> is (a b) mean "add b to the end of list a"?

No, it means "call the function `a` with the argument `b`".

Comment: That's wrong. `(list f 1 2)` does not call `list` with the arguments `f`, `1`and  `2`. Lisp evaluates the forms and calls `list` with the results as arguments. Similar `(a b)`. `a` is not called with the form `b`, but with the value of `b` as argument.

Answer (score 3):

`(list 1 2 3)` is a Lisp form which computes a fresh list of three values, the values of `1`, `2` and `3`.

`(1 2 3)` is a list and computes to an error, since the first element is a number, not a function. As a quoted list, it would be a literal list of the elements `1`, `2` and `3`.

`(list f 1 2)` calls the function `list` on the results of evaluating `f`, `1` and `2`. `f` is a variable and evaluation takes its value. `1` and `2` are numbers which evaluate to themselves. It returns a fresh list of three elements.

`(f 1 2)` calls the function `f` on the values of evaluating `1` and `2`, which are evaluating to themselves.

`((f 1) 2)` is not valid in Lisp. Some Lisp dialects, like Scheme, allow that. In Lisp the first element in a function form has to be a function name (or in Common Lisp a lambda form).

`(a b)` means call the function `a` on the value of evaluating `b`, which evaluates to the value of the variable `b`.

`append` is for appending lists.

Also no, 'Lisp' does not support currying.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's a clear difference between `(list f 1 2)` and `(f 1 2)`:
  * The first evaluates to `(#the value of <f># 1 2)`.
  * The second evaluates to the result of `f` applied to `1` and `2`.

Lisp functions don't do currying "out of the box", but they can be defined to do so.

`(a b)` means apply the function `a` to (the value of) `b`.

`append` *is* needed to append lists.

Comment: Does this mean that `(list f 1 2)` is equivalent to `(f' 1 2)`?

Comment: No. It _is_ similar to `'(f 1 2)`, but the `f` is not evaluated here. `(f' 1 2)` still evaluates a function called `f'`.

Comment: If we're talking about Common Lisp, `(list f 1 2)` contains a list whose first element is the value of the *variable* `f`, not the function `f`. If there is no variable `f`, it's an error.

Comment: @sepp2k Fair enough. I'm more used to Lisp 1s.